# Return multiple lines based on first line with queries from a second file

Tags: sed

I have a large file (~4,000,000 lines) consisting of multiple blocks of data, each with an introductory ID tag, and a list of selected ID tags in a second file.

For example:

Data.txt

```
>ID:1000
data about this
more data
data
>ID:1001
blah blah
data
>ID:1002
foo
...
```

And ID_Tags.txt

```
>ID:1000
>ID:1002
>ID:1085
>ID:3062
...
```

I need a way to grab the ID tag and corresponding data from Data.txt for the data specified in ID_Tags.txt so that I wind up with a file looking like:

Select_Data.txt

```
>ID:1000
data about this
more data
data
>ID:1002
foo
...
```

I can get one block of data at a time with

```
sed -n '/ID:1000/,/>/p' Data.txt | head -n -1 >> Select_Data.txt
```

But this only does a single ID tag at a time, and I have hundreds of select ID tags. Is there a way to avoid doing this manually?

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{tags[$0];next} /^>/{f=($0 in tags)} f' ID_Tags.txt Data.txt
>ID:1000
data about this
more data
data
>ID:1002
foo
```

Comment: While I already thought that [I found a nice solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31038692/171318), yours appears much cleaner. plus 1.

Comment: You're welcome. If/when you're ready to accept an answer remember to click on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{i[$1];next} NF>1 && $1 in i{print ">"$0}' RS='>' ids.txt data.txt
```

Output:

```
>ID:1000
data about this
more data
data
>ID:1002
etc
```

The key to my solution is to replace the default record separator `\n` by `>` using `RS='>'`. Using this trick it is pretty simple to access the individual fields of the data.

**Explanation**

We are passing both files to awk, *ids.txt* and *data.txt* and awk will process them in order.

`NR==FNR{i[$1];next}` runs unless awk is parsing the first file, *ids.txt*. `NR` represents the current record number, and `FNR` the number of the record in the current file. They are equal only when parsing the first file. `i[$1]` adds the value of the id (without the leading `>` since it is the field separator) as key to the array `i`. `next` stops further processing of the line.

`$1 in i {print ">"$0}` will check if the first column of the data record - the id - is a key in our array `i` and prints the record while adding the `>` back to the front of it.

Note that we are additionally checking if `NF>1` (meaning the record is not empty) because awk will return an empty first record because the data file starts with the record delimiter `>`. `<none> in array` will result into `true` in awk and would print and additional `>`.

Comment: In general you should test `NF`, not `$0`, to decide if a record is empty or not since a test on `$0` will fail if a value is present and evaluates numerically to zero. In this case I can't see how `$0` could undesirably evaluate to zero though since every record will start with `ID` but it's just a general rule of thumb. Testing for `NR>1` would be clearer in this case of course.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks Ed, I always appreciate you lectures! :)

Comment: I actually suggested `NF` alone (test for an empty record) or `NR>1` (test for the 2nd and subsequent records), not `NF>1` (test for more than one field in the record). Those early morning lectures are hard to focus in I guess :-).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
  sed $'1i:a\ns#.*#/^&$/bb#;$ad;:b;n;/^>/ba;bb' ids_file | sed -f - data_file
```

This builds a sed script from the ids file and runs the script against the data file. The sed script looks for those ids in the ids file and prints the id line and those lines following until the next id where it loops back check the id. All other lines are deleted.